# Redmine cron job to fetch emails (redmine:email:receive_imap) in docker

Tags: docker, email, cron, imap, redmine

Here a proposal to fetch emails and create tickets with a cronjob in a redmine container. I share it because it's been hard to find documentation about it. There's probably a better solution, but it works.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
  redmine:
    container_name: redmine
    build: configs
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:3000
    environment:
      - REDMINE_DB_MYSQL=mysql
      - REDMINE_DB_USERNAME=redmine
      - REDMINE_DB_DATABASE=redmine
      - REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD=password1234
    volumes:
      - ./configs/crontab.txt:/root/crontab.txt
      - ./configs/cronjob.sh:/root/cronjob.sh
```

**configs/Dockerfile**

```
FROM redmine:4.1.0

RUN set -ex; \
    apt update;  \
    apt install cron -y

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**configs/entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo >&2 "Start crontab"
service cron start
crontab /root/crontab.txt

# call parent entrypoint
exec /docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

**configs/crontab.txt**

```
* * * * * /root/cronjob.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# Empty space
```

**configs/cronjob.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# get env form printenv in container
export PATH=/usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/bundle
export RAILS_ENV=production
export HOME=/home/redmine
export BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=/usr/local/bundle
rake -f /usr/src/redmine/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV=production host=imap.host.com username=mail@host.com password=passw0rd port=993 ssl=true project=project_name assigned_to=group_name no_permission_check=1 unknown_user=accept move_on_success=read
```

Comment: Can you rephrase this as a question?

Comment: Yes, reprase like is there a better way, also I'll advice you to post this on Redmine's forums instead of stackoverflow, or at least post a stackoverflow link towards this question, there...

Answer (score 0):

I just found this simple way.
and it works,
edit your bash script. **cronjob.sh**.

vim /root/cronjob.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/src/redmine
rake -f /usr/src/redmine/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV=production host=imap.host.com username=mail@host.com password=passw0rd port=993 ssl=true project=project_name assigned_to=group_name no_permission_check=1 unknown_user=accept move_on_success=read >> /usr/src/redmine/log/imap.log 2>&1
```

use crontab on your docker **HOST**!
and dont forget enable autostart the cron service.

```
* * * * * docker exec -t redmine-container /root/cronjob.sh
#per-minute cron.
```

check your cron log if enable (**docker HOST**)

```
tail -n100 /var/log/cron
```

its running ?
check your imap cron log. ( **Redmine Container** )

```
tail -f /usr/src/redmine/log/imap.log
```

i currently run redmine 4.0.7. on docker(centos HOST).